# Woocommerce hook triggered when the order is received and thanks the user

Tags: wordpress, hook-woocommerce

In my plugin I'd like to know how to "intercept" when the user completes an order paying by wire transfer because I need to know the amount of the order to calculate something else and write into another table.
I thought that would be:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_thankyou_order_received_text', 'fn_payment_complete');
```

would that be the right way or is there a different way? Thanks! Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

woocommerce_thankyou_order_received_text is for returning msg. You can still use it to access order but i would recommend using woocommerce_thankyou instead.

**Using woocommerce_thankyou_order_received_text hook**

```
function wired_order_thank_you_msg($msg,$order) {
    //$order is object
    $payment_method = $order->get_payment_method(); //returns payment method bacs,cheque,cod etc
    if($payment_method === 'bacs'):
        //Do stuff
        $status = $order->get_status();
        $order_total = $order->get_formatted_order_total();

        //Return custom msg if you want
        $msg = array();
        $msg[] .= $status;
        $msg[] .= __('Custom msg','text');
        $msg[] .= $order_total;

        return sprintf('%s',implode($msg));
    else:
        return $msg;
    endif;

   
}
add_action('woocommerce_thankyou_order_received_text','wired_order_thank_you_msg',10,2);
```

**Using woocommerce_thankyou hook**

```
function wired_order_thank_you($order_id) {
    //$order is object
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    $payment_method = $order->get_payment_method(); //returns payment method bacs,cheque,cod etc

    if($payment_method === 'bacs'):
        //Do stuff
        $order_total = $order->get_formatted_order_total();
    endif;
}
add_action('woocommerce_thankyou','wired_order_thank_you',10,1);
```

Comment: Thanks Martin , at the end I decided to use woocommerce_order_payment_status_changed 's hook so I can do updates on another table when the user changes state of an order from suspended to completed....